# Deploy different WCF .svc files based on configuration

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a `Service1.svc` file that is a normal WCF service. If I deploy the WCF project it will happily copy the `Service1.svc` file along with the binaries and the other files. So far, so good. What I want is, based on the selected build configuration, or some other trick, to publish different contents for the `Service1.svc` file.

Let's say I have a `Service1.Conf1.svc` file and a `Service1.Conf2.svc` file and two configurations (like `Debug` or `Release`) that are named `Conf1` and `Conf2`. When I click publish and have the `Conf1` configuration selected, I want the publish folder to have a virtually created `Service1.svc` file whose contents are from `Service1.Conf1.svc`. When I click publish and have the `Conf2` configuration selected, I want the publish folder to have a virtually created `Service1.svc` file whose contents are from `Service1.Conf2.svc`.

I would like to have this for the publish action, not the build action (which could be achievable by a post-build or pre-build event). The main purpose is to adjust the contents of the `Service1.svc` file according to the publish environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We took a different approach and generate all required config/svc files for all possible installs (using TT file generation) and let the installer copy the correct configs/svc files (based on user selection during install).

The names of the files are constructed by inserting the target platform name into the standard name e.g web.local.config, web.dev.config, web.test.config etc

This way you can give one installer to anyone from any department. They just choose the platform.

Comment: it is a good idea. but i was first looking for same thing integrated into visual studio deploy process. but the tt idea is nice :)

Comment: We have dozens of related Web and Win hosted WCF services, as well as multiple websites and apps. The tt route (also with common master ttinclude files and endpoint snippet files) saved our necks.